# Call to undefined method getEntityManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony and I'm trying to run a basic SQL query but keep getting the error below. I am having a really hard time troubleshooting this. I was wondering if someone can please point me in the right direction and possibly explain what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Error:

```
Call to Undefined Method ... DefaultController::getEntityManager()
```

Entity (Company.php)

```
namespace Foo\FooBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

 /**
 *@ORM\Entity
 *@ORM\Table(name="company")
 */
class Company extends EntityRepository
{
   /**
     *@ORM\id
     *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
    */
    protected $name;

    /**
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=650)
    */
    protected $description;
}
```

Controller

```
public function searchAction($word)
{
        $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM company WHERE 
     MATCH(`keywords`) AGAINST(':word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
                  $stmt->bindValue('word ', $word);
                  $stmt->execute();
                  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

    ..etc, etc....
```

Comment: [Controller](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html) has no method `getEntityManager`. Try using `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As touki said in comment,

You should get the manager from doctrine:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

I see that you are posting many questions about symfony2, try to make a testing projet and generate entity, and CRUD for it.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
php app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

The generated code will help you understand how it works

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already generated an entity and crud :)